# error: git was not found - installing laravel with composer windows

Tags: php, git, laravel-4, composer-php

I'm getting an error saying:

```
failed to clone https://github.com/php-fig/log.git, git was not found, check that it is installed and in your PATH env.

'git' is not recognized as and internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

when I try and run `composer create-project laravel/laravel learning-laravel`.

I installed the git GUI which also comes with a command line shell, but I don't know why its not recognising the command (I'm issuing the create-project command in the normal windows command line prompt).

I also tried running the command from the git shell, which worked, but when I tried `php artisan serve` it gave me an error saying CLI has stopped working.

Does anyone know how to fix the git error? I'd rather use the windows command shell instead of the git one as it can then go into my wamp/www file

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add the directory you installed git to to your PATH environment variable.

1. Right click on `Computer`.
2. Click Advanced System Settings
3. Click Environment Variables inside the Advanced Menu
4. Under System Variables, scroll to `PATH`
5. Add `;"C:\path\to\git\bin";"C:\path\to\git\cmd"`

Test the git command in the command prompt to see if it worked. Git is usually located in `Program Files` or `Program Files(x86)`.

Comment: I already have both git paths in my system PATH, and windows command prompt recognizes git, yet composer doesn't see it.

Answer (score 2):

There is an easier (but temporal) way to add a path variable in Windows.

Paste this in your command prompt:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Git\bin
```

This will work for the rest of the command prompt session. Don't forget installing Git before this.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add git to your system PATH if you want to use it in regular command prompt.

Here's a guide on modifying your system path in Windows:

http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: any idea on how to do that? I've never done something like that before

Answer (score 0):

you need to uninstall git and reinstall ( or update ) in the options you need to change from git bash only to allow git to be added to command line as well, also since it then adds it to your path you may or may not need to restart your computer

Comment: or you can add it to your path yourself like the other answers have suggested

Answer (score 0):

I was having some issues using git on Windows. I found this information only and it worked for me.

http://ccn.ucla.edu/wiki/index.php/Setting_Up_and_Using_Git#Windows

Answer (score 0):

I found That I haven't Installed Git in my new system so, while I tried to installed new Laravel project it gives me an error that git not found at this path.

So make sure you have **installed and configure GIT in your System** before install/Create new Laravel Project.

Hope this helpful to you!!!

Thanks,
Vatsal.