# PhpStorm add Yii2 dependency issue with git

Tags: git, yii, yii2, composer-php, phpstorm

I have tried installing Yii2 with PhpStorm UI and I always get the same error

[image]

[image]

I always get the same error about git was not found.

I do have git installed with github and it is not configured to run from the shell. I have specified the correct git.exe path in PhpStorm settings but still have this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have `git` available in the `$PATH` scope.

Most probably you do not have Git install. [Download Git](https://git-scm.com/download/win) and install it, then try to update your dependencies.

Comment: I do have the git installed, but it is not configured as environment variable. I can commit through phpStorm and GitHub for windows.
Is there a way to avoid adding git to environment variables ?

Comment: I don't have any other good idea to avoid this problem. Why don't you want to add Git to env vars? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169348/error-git-was-not-found-installing-laravel-with-composer-windows

Comment: I added git. Now when I type git in command prompt it does work. In phpstorm I still get the same error. This is probably some other issue. I don't have any clues.

Comment: Try to add it here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/path-variables-2.html

Comment: The problem was that my antivirus was blocking connection to github from PhpStorm. Thank you for your time!!